# Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: apache, http, centos

My web server with Centos and Apache suddenly starting showing the error:

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

It happens in *every* browser. Cookies have been deleted. They are not the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any rewrite rules?  Sometimes this can be caused by a malformed rewrite rule in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the root of the problem, but it was solved when I stopped SE Linux.
Stopping SE Linux (Command Line):

```
sudo setenforce 0
```

Edit: Upon further investigation, I was able to use:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

It's odd that the error suddenly started to occur after months of usage, but after setting those selinux configs, I was able to setenforce 1 and everything worked.

For the record, before doing all that I did attempt a reboot.

Helpful source: https://tag1consulting.com/blog/stop-disabling-selinux

SELINUX LOGS: /var/logs/audit/audit.log